# How do I find the unknown constants, given the limit?

Tags: calculus

The equation is

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \Big(\frac{6a}{1-e^2x} + \frac{b}{x}\Big) = 24\,\,.$$

I used L'Hopital's rule to simplify the equation since the original one would give an indeterminate form, but afterwards it would give $0 + 0 = 24$, which doesn't add up. Which part did I make a mistake in?

Comment: You should get $a=8, b=24$. Unless you show complete work we cannot say where you went wrong.

Comment: Why would L'Hopital's rule apply? It's not a tool to hammer every nail in sight, you have understand the conditions to use it. When are the only times you are allowed to use L'Hopital from your notes?

Comment: when x approaches to 0 , 1-e^2x = 0, and the eqn would become 6a/0 + b/0 which is indeterminate so i found the derivative of 6a/(1-e^2x) to be 0/-2e^2x and derivative of b/x to be 0/1. If i dont use L'Hopital' rule to rewrite the equation what should I use?

Comment: Those are not indeterminate forms for L'Hopital's rule. They must always be a fraction, either $\infty/\infty$ or $0/0$. Your expression currently is neither. Can you find a way to rewrite a $+$ as $/$?

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. Now, I've got (6a-2be^2x) / [1-e^2x(2x+1)] I can't use L'Hopital's rule again since it is no longer a 0/0 form however the denominator is still a 0 when x is 0.